# Are there analogues of eigenvalues/eigenvectors for a ring homomorphism/endomorphism?

Tags: ring-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My question is very simple. To put it in a context, a linear transformation is nothing but a homomorphism from a vector space to another. I usually visualize the action of a linear transformation by thinking of what it does to the unit hypersphere. Eigenvectors together with their eigenvalues describe the axes of action in this case.

I couldn't find an explicit reference to any sort of analogue of this phenomenon to ring homomorphisms/endomorphisms. Specifically, is there a standard way to describe the action of a ring homomorphism/endomorphism in the described sense? Even more specifically, what would be the analogue of an orthogonal transformation (with all eigenvalues modulus 1) in the realm of ring homomorphisms/endomorphisms?

edit: I believe now that I asked my question in a rather haphazard way. But I am keeping the first two paragraphs intact. I am not a mathematician and in the past few years I taught myself what it looks like almost completely ignoring technical details and first concentrating on the concepts. What I would be asking is in fact what the set of all ring homomorphisms/endomorphisms (from a ring to itself/to another one) look like? Can I introduce any metric/criteria to distinguish them, saying these are well behaving and these are not, just like I can do for linear transformations?

Comment: Having "all eigenvalues 1" does not characterize orthogonal transformations at all. I guess you mean "eigenvalues all *modulus* 1"?

Comment: Yes. modulus 1.

Comment: That still doesn't characterize orthogonal transformations (you also need an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors).

Comment: Well, yes! I am not so careful about being rigorous. But, I believe what I mean is clear. It's a conceptual question.

Comment: Actually, I think that the proper generalisation to the ring setting of linear transformations are module homomorphisms. Moreover, having a norm adds a lot of extra structure, so it is not a trivial assumption at all (this is quite a conceptual issue, too).

Answer (score 1):

You can't talk about the eigenvectors of a linear transformation between two different vector spaces. You can only talk about the eigenvectors of a linear transformation from a vector space to itself. So the analogous question is about ring endomorphisms, but ring endomorphisms are complicated in general and don't admit a description anywhere near as simple as the description of linear transformations.

For example, understanding the behavior of ring endomorphisms of $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is highly nontrivial and leads to complicated phenomena like [Julia sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_set). The elements of [Galois groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_group) are also ring endomorphisms, and understanding Galois groups is also a major problem (e.g. understanding the [absolute Galois group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_Galois_group) of the rationals is a major goal of modern number theory).

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. What if I have a homomorphism?

Comment: Ring homomorphisms are also just difficult to understand in general. You may want to learn some commutative algebra and algebraic geometry to see how they can be understood geometrically in some sense.

Comment: I am grateful to you, indeed. The reason I am (roughly) asking about this issue is that there is a problem that I am trying to devise an attacking plan and I only have a rough idea about algebraic geometry and in particular what schemes are. But, I had the sense that morphisms between schemes are in one to one correspondence between ring homomorphisms/endomorphisms? after hopelessely leafing through hard texts. I am not so sure. The problem at hand requires distinguishing between well behaving homomorphisms and badly behaving ones.

Comment: @user: the correct statement is that morphisms between _affine_ schemes $\text{Spec } S \to \text{Spec } R$ are in one-to-one correspondence with ring homomorphisms $R \to S$. The situation for non-affine schemes is more complicated. What do you mean by "badly behaving"?

Comment: Recall that I am still in the rough thinking mode. The right question would be "Is there any interesting property which classifies homomorphisms?" or better assigns any quantity to them. I sense that there should be. This is what I mean by well behaving and badly behaving.

Comment: @user: that depends on what you want to do. This seems like a vague question. One option is to think geometrically and look at the induced maps on various cohomology theories for schemes. But whether this is reasonable depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the equation $Tx=\lambda x$. Since the $x$ is in both sides, it looks like $T:R\to R$ for the equation to make sense, and moreover we need to figure out what $\lambda$ is, whether it is just from $R$ or from some module action on elements of $R$.

I'll call $x$ and "eigenelement" of $R$. As with vector spaces, you'll have no problem verifying that eigenelements corresponding to the same eigenvalue $\lambda$ form a subgroup of $R$. In order to form a right ideal of $R$, though, we would need $T(xr)=\lambda xr$ for arbitrary $r\in R$. This is even unlikely when $R$ is commutative, for we have that $T(xr)=T(r)\lambda x$, and there is no guarantee that $T(r)=r$. So, hope is lost for "eigenideals" of $R$.

I suppose this means that you can talk about "eigensubgroups of $R$", but I've never heard anything like this leading to a useful decomposition of $R$. Certainly it would be unusual for it to turn out to play well with the multiplicative structure.

Things get a little better if you allow yourself to consider a $K$ algebra $R$ for a commutative ring $K$. In this case, you would also be requring the ring endomorphism $T$ to be $K$ linear. Accordingly, $R$ is just a $K$ module, and your ring endomorphism is *a fortiori* a $K$ module homomorphism. That would allow $K$-eigenvectors to be described for $T$, but they would only be giving information about $T$ as a $K$ linear enomorphism of $K$ modules, and it wouldn't have much to say about the fact that $T$ is multiplicative.

Comment: Thanks for the meticulous answer. Your answer clearly shows that rings are much more complicated. What I am looking rougly is though to distinguish between "good" homomorphisms (analogue of orthogonal transformations) and "bad" homomorphisms. Maybe, there is another way of doing so.

Comment: @user73260 You give me too much credit: it was just a rough ad-hoc explanation. The term "orthogonal" only has meaning when there is some inner product (or bilinear form) on the space. What inner product are you thinking of?

Comment: I am not thinking of any inner products. I believe now that I asked my question in a rather haphazard way. I am not a mathematician and in the past few years I taught myself what it looks like almost completely ignoring technical details and concentrating on the concepts. What I would be asking is in fact what the set of all ring homomorphisms/endomorphisms (from a ring to itself/to another one) look like? Can I introduce any metric/criteria to distinguish them, saying these are well behaving and these are not, just like I can do for linear transformations?

Comment: @user73260 If the ring had a positive definite inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ then yes, you could talk about orthogonal transformations as those satisfying $\langle x,y \rangle=\langle Tx,Ty \rangle$. Still, since the ring multiplication doesn't usually have anything to do with the inner product, it doesn't add anything.